# TMENU for different Domain root_ids in Typo3 HMENU

Tags: typo3

is it possible to build a typo3 hmenu/tmenu for a single typo3 installation and multiple domainrecords in this installation which shows at the frontend for each domain the according menu structure?

for example:

```
domain-1 (root_id = 1) uid=23
   |-home
   |-contact
   |-product of domain 1

domain-1 (root_id = 2) uid=33
   |-home
   |-contact
   |-whatsoever of domain 2
   |-contact
```

how can i create with only one hmenu for each domain the correct menu output?

a appreciate any help

thanks a lot

Ludwig

Comment: You could use ``entryLevel``, but I suggest to simply create a condition for each domain and set the starting ``uid`` accordingly. I always use a constant for this and create an extension template for each domain.

Answer (score 0):

A) Simplest Typoscript template example:

```
temp.menu = HMENU
temp.menu {
    special = directory
    special {
        value = 23
    }
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        wrap = <ul>|</ul>
        NO {
            allWrap = <li>|</li>
        }
    }
}

[PIDinRootline = 33]
    temp.menu {
        special {
            value = 33
        }
    }
[global]
```

B) Another possibility is to create for each domain page extension TypoScript template.

Main Typoscript (global):

```
temp.menu = HMENU
temp.menu {
    special = directory
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        wrap = <ul>|</ul>
        NO {
            allWrap = <li>|</li>
        }
    }
}
```

Extended Typoscript (domain-1):

```
temp.menu {
    special {
        value = 23
    }
}
```

Extended Typoscript (domain-2):

```
temp.menu {
    special {
        value = 33
    }
}
```

**It depends on what it looks like whole Typo3 page tree.**